# Cancel multiple queued commands

Tags: windows-explorer

With a casual accidental drag I seem to have selected 15 years of source code to each in turn run, launching Delphi, picture viewer, notepad and whatever else.

Is there a way to cancel this command without closing every individual thing?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's not much you can do about this.  Either attempt to log out or wait for everything to finish churning.

I thought that Explorer would prompt you if you attempted to open up more than a handful of items at once though.

Comment: You would think so wouldn't you. It's Windows2000 if that makes a difference. Best technique is to let half of it open then kill the app in CMD. I hope it doesn't corrupt any of my archived code though :(

Comment: Being Win2k might be the problem -- I don't remember the warning before XP.  Try logging out.  That might interrupt things.